# CVS result shows in one column

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have this csv export code.
the export I working well but my only problem is that the result is showing only in one column

the problem happens only when I try to convert the file to UTF-8,
is there another way around this?

```html
    $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
$link->set_charset("utf8");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM weekevents";
  $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    $col = "col1,col2,col3,col4 \n";//Column headers
    foreach ($query as $record){
        $cam = explode(';', $record['cam']);
$col .= $record['weekday'].','.$record['week']
      ;
    }
$filename = date("m-Y");

    $csv_handler = fopen ('C:/xampp/htdocs/rge/main-rtl/uploads/שיבוץ חודש -'.$filename.'.csv','w');
    fwrite ($csv_handler, $col);
    fclose ($csv_handler);

    echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';
```

[image]

Comment: Use [`putcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: CSV comes with various flavours. What is the expected field separator in your spread sheet program? For example MS Excel expects in Germany `;`.

Comment: in Israel its ,

Comment: Please share with us the CSV file. And please fix the typo in your caption ("CVS result shows...")

Comment: this is my csv file https://ufile.io/mm44u

Comment: It seems your field separator is wrong. Captions: col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4. Data: data1`,`data2`<<space>>`data3`<<space>>`data4

Comment: how can I encode the file to UTF-8 ?